# MPV player is not controlled by bluetooth device (play/pause) on Ununtu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04, mpv-media-player

I play a video in MPV and try to pause/play using my Bluetooth headset's buttons (JBL). Sometimes it works, but mostly it doesn't. With VLC player controls work perfectly.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: I just got a some Bluetooth adapters, and noticed that the pause/mute feature didn't work with mpv, either (on Xubuntu 22.04).